# Record my Android screen as GIF movie

Tags: gratis, android, screen-recording, gif

I want to make a small tutorial in my Android phone running Lollipop 5.1.1 (rooted) by recording screen as GIF. Are there any apps that could produce solution to this?

I have gone through apps that record through phone's camera and convert it into a GIF image, but I want the app, that records the screen to GIF.

I don't want to record screen and take out the video and edit it in my desktop, as I am fed up with that process for even 30 seconds tutorial. Also I dont want to mirror my screen to PC and record using software that convert screen to GIF.

The app should be free of cost.

Comment: There's a bunch of [screen recording apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_screenrecording). Have you checked any of those? For example, [Super Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tianxingjian.screenshot) explicitly mentions GIF (but comes with several ad and analytics modules). [Screen Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screen.recorder.video) also has GIF support and seems more permission-/privacy-friendly.

Comment: @Izzy will try and let you know.

Comment: Usually I do that recording the device emulator with Snagit: https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html. It's a paid software but worth it's price ;). You can record the video and than save as GIF.